# Retrieving only string values from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

As you can see from the image above underlined in red, I have a child that has a String value along with an Int Value. Now is it possible to retrieve only the String value? At the moment I'm using the code below but it retrieves the string and Int values not just the string value. I can't seem to figure how to isolate the string value. Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(self.userUID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
    let uid = dictionary[""] as! String
    print("uid")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(self.userUID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
for child in snapshot.children {
  let c = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
  print(c.key)
 }
})
```

Here your snapshot is the `userid` and then you add a `for` loop to iterate inside the children of the `userid` and get the key of those children in the print.

Example:

```
 J2xb677oeCNhDMVW2WRwHeBzirM2
```